# Collection to hold multiple objects of classes in c#

Tags: c#, database, oop, collections, categories

> **So my question what is the best way to categorize groups of items that you collect from a database?**

This is what I have so far

```
enum IdOfCategory
{
    Fruits = 1,
    Bakery = 2,
}

public class Categories
{
    public Collection categories = new Collection();

    public Categories()
    {
        categories.Add(new Fruits());
        categories.Add(new Bakery());
    }
}

 public class Fruits
{
    string query = $"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryId = {(int)IdOfCategory.Bakery}";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\mario.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    //Adding items to collection
            }
        }
}

 public class Bakery
{
    //the same as above class
}
```

My table has the following columns ProductId, ProductName, ProductDescription, CategoryId

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward problem.  Normally I just put a `CategoryId` as a property in any entity that I want to categorize.  You can store the categories in a Categories table, with `CategoryId` as the primary key.  If you want to store multiple categories for each object, you need a linking table containing CategoryId and a foreign key to your entity.

Comment: It would be better if you gave us a little more detail about what you're trying to accomplish *in your problem domain,* and a little less detail about your proposed solution.  See http://xyproblem.info for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

For an example, you can use interfaces:

```
public interface IFood
{
    // has some properties, fields, methods, etc.
}

public class Fruits : IFood
{
    // implements properties, fields, methods, etc from interface
}

public class Bakery : IFood
{
    // implements properties, fields, methods, etc from interface
}
```

Then:

```
public class Categories
{
    public IEnumerable<IFood> CategoriesList;

    public Categories()
    {
        CategoriesList = new List<IFood> { new Fruits(), new Bakery() };
    }
}
```